# Redirect to www and eliminate fb_xd_fragment

Tags: regex, facebook, apache, .htaccess

I've been trying all all day to combine these two rewrites into just one -or get both to work consecutively-. They work perfectly well on their own, but not together.

I need to redirect in apache all access to a website to a "www" subdomain, and at the same time I need to eliminate the "fb_xd_fragment" added by facebook; while keeping intact any other query strings.

This are the two separate pieces:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)fb_xd_fragment(=)?$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Both rewrites work well separately, but not together. If uploaded in that order, the final result is to non-www, as the second code uses the original URI. And if I change the order, then it redirects to a www, but without any query string; which I need intact except the fb_xd_fragment piece.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `L` after the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)fb_xd_fragment(=)?$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I tried that the first day in the tester I'm using (http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) and it doesn't work. However, out of curiosity, I tried in the root .htaccess of my website, and it does work.
But, isn't the first [R=310, L] telling it it's the last rule it should process; then why will it continue to the "fb_xd_fragment" rule?
I'd imagined it wouldn't work, as the test confirmed.

Comment: Another issue, it only works if I add both to the root .htaccess; but I needed the "fb_xd_fragment" to work only on two subfolders, and not on the whole website. So, how can I do to have the "www" to process the whole website, and the "fb_xd_fragment" to work only on two subfolders? I tried breaking it down, leaving the "www" in the root .htaccess, and the "fb_xd_fragment" in two .htaccess in the targer folders; but again it doens't work...